# How to fix broken CMOS after pc battery replace

Tags: boot, bios, hardware-failure, battery, cmos

I recently changed my PC's battery (not the CMOS' battery, the PC's main battery). After that, whenever I boot my PC I get the "Invalid CMOS checksum" error. Therefore, the BIOS settings reset to default on every system boor. I have tried reinstalling the BIOS and resetting the CMOS.

I also opened the computer to see if I could change the CMOS battery. When I did, I could not find the CMOS battery anywhere. After some research, I discovered that my particular PC model has no CMOS battery. It powers the CMOS with the PC's battery.

It might be important to mention that the clock gets off when ever I power off the PC. I really don't know what else to do, and **I have not found anything that addresses this particular issue on a PC with no separate CMOS battery**. Hence, I post the question here: is there anything I can do to fix this? Could I have damaged the PC CMOS when replacing its battery?

**UPDATE**: My PC is an HP laptop. The model is 15-da0011la. It has a HP HT03XL battery (L11119-855).

Comment: Is this a laptop?  What battery?  The main laptop battery? Changing these does not affect CMOS.

Comment: maybe a jumper on the motherboard fell off ... or, if you were moving jumpers, then you may have put one in the wrong place

Comment: I would be inclined to take the computer to a local shop for troubleshooting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @John normally changing the main laptop battery should not affect the CMOS. But as I mention in the post, this specific laptop model has no separate battery for the CMOS. The CMOS is powered using the main laptop battery. And the problem appeared when I replaced the main laptop battery.

Comment: I assume you have tried to fully charge the battery?

Comment: @Ramhound yes I did

Comment: Have you tried to change a setting within UEFI and save the changes while keeping the machine plugged in, in hopes of resaving your configuration so their isn’t a checksum issue?

Comment: @Ramhound I am not sure if I know what you mean, but yes I have tried changing some settings in the BIOS. When I reboot the system, the BIOS settings are overwritten by the default BIOS settings. Why would changing the settings while keeping the machine plugged be different?

Comment: HP generally has great service manuals, and it might be worth taking a look to see if there's anything helpful there.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000124377/how-to-perform-a-bios-or-cmos-reset-and-clear-the-nvram-on-dell-systems ?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Or maybe https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/ish_3932413-2337994-16 ?